# Racket: how to sort dot-separated numbers

Tags: scheme, racket

How does one sort dot-separates numbers, like version numbers of software, in Racket?

For example

```
'("1.1.2" "1.0.0" "1.3.3" "1.0.7" "1.0.2")
```

sorted into

```
'("1.0.0" "1.0.2" "1.0.7" "1.1.2" "1.3.3")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split each string up on `#\.` and turn it into a list of numbers, and sort based on that transformation. Example using [SRFI-67](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-67/srfi-67.html) to compare lists:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require srfi/67)

(define versions '("1.1.2" "1.0.0" "1.12.1" "1.3.3" "1.0.7" "1.0.2"))

(define (sort-versions vlst)
  (sort vlst (lambda (a b) (< (list-compare integer-compare a b) 0))
        #:key (lambda (v) (map string->number (string-split v ".")))
        #:cache-keys? #t))

(writeln (sort-versions versions))
```

Comment: Alternative equivalent `less-than?` predicate using a higher-order SRFI-67 constructor: `(<? (lambda (a b) (list-compare integer-compare a b)))`, or if you also `(require srfi/26)`, `(<? (cut list-compare integer-compare <> <>))` is a bit shorter and personally cleaner.

Comment: The technique of sorting a transformed version of the elements but returning the original values is known as *decorate-sort-undecorate*, and racket's `sort` makes it easy to apply with the `#:key` transformer.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Scheme from scratch:

```
;; Convert a character into a number
;; Example: (char->number #\3) => 3

(define (char->number char)
  (case char
    ((#\0) 0)
    ((#\1) 1)
    ((#\2) 2)
    ((#\3) 3)
    ((#\4) 4)
    ((#\5) 5)
    ((#\6) 6)
    ((#\7) 7)
    ((#\8) 8)
    ((#\9) 9)))

;; Convert a list of characters into a decimal number.
;; Example: (list->decimal '(#\1 #\2 #\3)) => 123

(define (list->decimal digits)
  (let loop ((digits digits)
             (value 0))
    (if (pair? digits)
        (loop (cdr digits)
              (+ (* value 10)
                 (char->number (car digits))))
        value)))

;; Convert a version string into list of decimals.
;; Example: (version->list "1.2.3") => (1 2 3)

(define (version->list version)
  (let loop ((chars    (string->list version))
             (fragment '())
             (result   '()))
    (if (pair? chars)
        (let ((char (car chars))
              (chars (cdr chars)))
          (if (char=? char #\.)
              (loop chars
                    '()
                    (cons (list->decimal fragment)
                          result))
              (loop chars
                    (cons char fragment)
                    result)))
        (reverse (cons (list->decimal fragment)
                       result)))))

;; Convert a list of version numbers into a string.
;; Example: (list->version '(1 2 3)) => "1.2.3"

(define (list->version numbers)
  (let loop ((numbers numbers)
             (result "")
             (delimiter ""))
    (if (pair? numbers)
        (loop (cdr numbers)
              (string-append result
                             delimiter
                             (number->string (car numbers)))
              ".")
        result)))

;; Check if a version is lower than the other.
;; Example: (version<? '(1 2 3) '(1 2)) => #f

(define (version<? v1 v2)
  (if (pair? v1)
      (if (pair? v2)
          (let ((m1 (car v1))
                (m2 (car v2)))
            (cond
             ((< m1 m2) #t)
             ((> m1 m2) #f)
             (else (version<? (cdr v1)
                              (cdr v2)))))
          #f)
      (if (pair? v2)
          #t
          #f)))

;; Sort versions.

(define (sort-versions versions)
  (map list->version
       (sort version<?
             (map version->list versions))))

;; Example

(let ((unsorted '("1.1.2" "1.0.0" "1.3.3" "1.0.7" "1.0.2"))
      (sorted   '("1.0.0" "1.0.2" "1.0.7" "1.1.2" "1.3.3")))
  (equal? (sort-versions unsorted)
          sorted))
```

The above converts all version strings into lists of decimals, sorts the list and converts the lists of decimals back into strings. The last step can be avoided as explained in Shawn's answer. This makes it necessary to preserve the original version string while sorting the versions. This is possible by boxing both representations of the version. The comparison has to unbox the list representation. The result is created by unboxing the string representation. The following shows this alternative implementation.

```
;; Convert a character into a number
;; Example: (char->number #\3) => 3

(define (char->number char)
  (case char
    ((#\0) 0)
    ((#\1) 1)
    ((#\2) 2)
    ((#\3) 3)
    ((#\4) 4)
    ((#\5) 5)
    ((#\6) 6)
    ((#\7) 7)
    ((#\8) 8)
    ((#\9) 9)))

;; Convert a list of characters into a decimal number.
;; Example: (list->decimal '(#\1 #\2 #\3)) => 123

(define (list->decimal digits)
  (let loop ((digits digits)
             (value 0))
    (if (pair? digits)
        (loop (cdr digits)
              (+ (* value 10)
                 (char->number (car digits))))
        value)))

;; Convert a version string into list of decimals.
;; Example: (version->list "1.2.3") => ("1.2.3" 1 2 3)

(define (version->list version)
  (let loop ((chars    (string->list version))
             (fragment '())
             (result   '()))
    (if (pair? chars)
        (let ((char (car chars))
              (chars (cdr chars)))
          (if (char=? char #\.)
              (loop chars
                    '()
                    (cons (list->decimal fragment)
                          result))
              (loop chars
                    (cons char fragment)
                    result)))
        (cons version
              (reverse (cons (list->decimal fragment)
                             result))))))

;; Convert a list of version numbers into a string.
;; Example: (list->version '("1.2.3" 1 2 3)) => "1.2.3"

(define list->version car)

;; Check if a version is lower than the other.
;; Example: (version<? '("1.2.3" 1 2 3) '("1.2" 1 2)) => #f

(define (version<? v1 v2)
  (let loop ((v1 (cdr v1))
             (v2 (cdr v2)))
    (if (pair? v1)
        (if (pair? v2)
            (let ((m1 (car v1))
                  (m2 (car v2)))
              (cond
               ((< m1 m2) #t)
               ((> m1 m2) #f)
               (else (loop (cdr v1)
                           (cdr v2)))))
            #f)
        (if (pair? v2)
            #t
            #f))))

;; Sort versions.

(define (sort-versions versions)
  (map list->version
       (sort version<?
             (map version->list versions))))

;; Example

(let ((unsorted '("1.1.2" "1.0.0" "1.3.3" "1.0.7" "1.0.2"))
      (sorted   '("1.0.0" "1.0.2" "1.0.7" "1.1.2" "1.3.3")))
  (equal? (sort-versions unsorted)
          sorted))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each string `"X.Y.Z"` into a number, sort the list of numbers, and convert the numbers back to strings.  You can use lots of ideas of encoding X.Y.Z as a number, for example, [Goedel's encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), etc, etc.